# Facebook connect integration: login from a custom screen

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to allow a user wishing to login through facebook in my site use a screen from my website, and not the popup provided by facebook.

Regards,
Pankaj

Comment: Check out this links it may helps you..its working code http://www.developerscode.com/2011/03/simple-way-to-integrate-facebook-login.html

Answer (score 1):

No. To authenticate via oAuth, You need to go to Facebook's "access grant" page.